# How does PCIe card vendors sign option ROMs?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, uefi, pci-express, secure-boot

If secure boot is enabled UEFI system would permit to run only signed Option ROMs.
I presume PCIe card vendors want their devices to work even if Secure Boot is enabled. Therefore how does PCIe card vendors sign option ROMs for their devices?

Currently I see 3 ways:

1. Ask Microsoft to sign their OPROM. This looks like the most easy way as Microsoft `KEK` is present in every UEFI firmware as a standard. But it looks like a paid service. How does it organized? How much does it cost? What kind of audit Microsoft performs? Does vendor suppose to provide source code of their drivers to Microsoft? So many questions.
2. Major vendors like Intel/AMD/NVIDIA can ask motherboard vendors to include their own `KEK` key in UEFI firmware similar to Microsoft. In such case PCIe device driver update from OS can update `db`/`dbx` databases and add necessary keys for OPROMs. But for some reasons I haven't heard about this approach. Also it is only possible for major PCIe card vendors. Motherboard vendors wouldn't add `KEK`'s for every PCIe card vendor.
3. Don't sign at all. This way PCIe devices with OPROM wouldn't work in UEFI if Secure Boot is enabled. Graphic cards wouldn't provide GOP, so you'll get a black screen on boot stage, network cards wouldn't expose PXE, and so on. This sounds bad.

Which approach PCIe card vendors usually use? Or is there another solution?

Also I don't really understand how OPROM images can support `dbx` mechanics.
If some key in `db` was used to sign something which was later revealed to have an exploit, this key should be revoked and added to `dbx`. It is easy to update bootloader on OS update, but how to update PCIe OPROM image in such case?